# SSRS Parameter Specify Values - Expression Not Working

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

In SSRS, I am trying to use an expression to specify the available value for a text box parameter.  I have tried several different things but my text box never gets populated with data. For the purpose of this post I have made the expression as simple as possible.  Below is an example.  The parameter is defined as single-value, non-blank, non-null, and visible.

**Custom Code**:

```
 Public Shared Function TestFunc() as String
     return "test"
 End Function
```

**Parameter Label**: `=Code.TestFunc()`
**Parameter Value**: `=Code.TestFunc()`

In this simple example I would expect the text box parameter to have the value 'test' but this is not the case.  What am I missing here?  Is there a different syntax or a setting that I'm unaware of?

Comment: I just tried what you described and it worked for me. Must be a small error somewhere. Try process of elimination. Or include links to screenshots of all the properties to see if we can spot what's off.

Comment: Ok so I changed the order of my parameters and I can get it to work only if its the first parameter in the list.  Any position other than first and the parameter is not populated.  This is very strange behavior.

Comment: Looks like this is by design: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/490845/ssrs-weird-parameters-order-bug-parameter-grayed

Comment: Once you specify a value for the first parameter and then tab over to the second one, does it populate then?

Comment: Isn't every MS SSRS bug "by design"? :p

Comment: Yes, if you specify a value for the first parameter and tab over, the second parameter will be populated. @StevenWhite